# Cycles: Generate 3d coordinates before modifier stack is resolved

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, coordinates, texture-coordinates

Im trying to create a volumetric material that uses a 3d texture. I need this volumetric to be animated along a curve. Right now, I have the material using generated coordinates. But the 3d texture does not bend with the object. Is there a way I can have a 3d coordinate space that is calculated before the bend of the object? Or perhaps a way to bend my coordinates to match the geometry?

Repro Steps:

-Create a cylinder with multiple divisions down its length.

-Rotate the cylinder 90* on the Y axis

-Scale the cylinder to 1,1,4

-Create a curve and add a curve modifier to the cylinder using the created curve

-In cycles create a musgrave texture with Generated texture coordinates as the vector input

-Create a colour ramp to clamp the texture values

-Create an emmisive shader and plug the colour ramp into the color of the shader

-plug the shader into the volumetric output

-notice how the texture does not curve with the geometry

Comment: Have you tried using the object coordinates?

Comment: yes, it appears that object coordinates, like the generated coordinates are defined by the bounding box of the object after all modifiers have been applied. thanks for the suggestion, unfortunate it doesn't work.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.  Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: I cant share my file as its for a project under nda. I can however give detailed repro steps.

Comment: Maybe you can create a "simplified" or "dummy" file file instead...

Comment: I have wodered this myself, as far as I know this isn't currently possible. Commonly this is done with using UV coordinates , but I don't think that would work with volumetric textures

Comment: I tried it via Vector Transform node but couldn't quite get the effect you're looking for because it only applies the difference in transforms for that object and transform doesn't receive the 3D transform generated by the curve modifier. Cycles in only able to read the physical 3D point for volume. In theory, using python that could be converted into angular coordinates X, Y and curve progress Z by finding nearest point N on curve and finding XY on the plane defined by N and curve tangent at N. So no. Maybe this could be done with particles and their object coordinate?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51349/how-to-align-a-volumetric-texture-along-curve

Comment: Anyone have an update to this question that utilizes the capabilities of Geometry Nodes as of v3.0 or later?

Answer (score 8):

It can be done!

## Approaching it on a Surface

Before we try to do this with a 3-dimensional texture, let's attempt it in 2-dimensions. This is actually fairly straightforward. We can create a proxy mesh by duplicating our object (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), removing the modifiers from our duplicated object, then setting the *Texture Mesh* setting for our original object to the mesh of the second object:

[image: Mesh properties panel]

Result:

[image: render result]

Hey, that works perfectly! Unfortunately, it doesn't work for 3D textures. When we attempt this with a volumetric texture it does absolutely nothing.

## Approaching it in a Volume

The best way to do this in a volume (believe me, I've tested others) is to create a proxy mesh, then take the coordinates from the proxy mesh.

#### What should our proxy mesh look like?

Unfortunately, Blender does not provide an easy way to transfer volumetric data on and off of meshes. Our saving grace is the **Point Density** node in Cycles. The **Point Density** node will create a volumetric texture based off of the vertices of any mesh, and interpolate between them. It follows, then, that our coordinate proxy mesh should be a 3D grid of points.

#### Creating the proxy mesh

We'll start by adding a plane, then in **Edit Mode**, moving and scaling it so it has the same size and location of the bottom of the cylinder's bounding box (in the image, I enabled the bounding box display):

[image: plane in edit mode]

Next, we need to have more points in our coordinate grid. Use the *Loop Cut* tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) to add lots of loop cuts in both directions, trying to make the faces roughly square (I did $63$ and $15$, to get a $64\times16$ grid:

[image: subdivided plane]

Next, in **Object Mode** add an *Array* modifier. Use *Constant Offset* in the $Z$ direction to create a "stack" of planes (I used an offset of $0.125$). Add enough planes to fill the bounding box of the cylinder:

[image: stack of planes]

Apply the *Array* modifier and add a *Curve* modifier. Set up the *Curve* modifier the same way that it is set up on the cylinder. Check to make sure everything deforms properly (proxy mesh set to Wireframe display):

[image: checking deformation]

Now the hard part:

#### Creating a coordinate system

The **Point Density** node can only take color from Vertex Colors, Weights, and Normals. By far the most customizable of these options is Vertex Colors. We need to find a way to put Texture Coordinates into Vertex Colors.

Let's use **[Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes)**! After downloading and installing the add-on, go into the **Node Editor** and add a new NodeTree.

Before we start adding nodes, we need to figure out how to emulate Generated texture coordinates. According to the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html):

> **Generated**
>   Automatically-generated texture coordinates from the vertex positions of the mesh without deformation, keeping them sticking to the surface under animation. Range from 0.0 to 1. 0 over the bounding box of the undeformed mesh.

This means we need to normalize the vectors representing the positions of our vertices and put them in the positive-positive-positive octant. Here is the formula we will use:

$$\mathbf p'=\frac{\mathbf p - \mathbf c}{\mathbf d} + \mathbf{0.5}$$

where $\mathbf p$ is a point in 3D space, $\mathbf c$ is the center of the bounding box, and $\mathbf d$ is the vector of the longest diagonal of the bounding box (i.e. the dimensions).

Let's get our inputs first. Add the following nodes (press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to bring up the list of nodes or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to search):

[image: input nodes]

The object in the *Object Input* node is our coordinate proxy object. The text in the *Object Attribute* node is `dimensions`. Note that "Use Modifiers" is unchecked. This ensures that the coordinates we get don't include the *Curve* modifier. Next, we'll use *Vector Math* nodes to implement the above formula:

[image: vector math nodes]

The *Convert* node will be added automatically. We have one more issue with the texture coordinates: texture coordinates are encoded in a linear color space, while Vertex Colors are encoded in **[sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB)**. From the linked Wikipedia page, we get the formula for encoding colors in **sRGB**:

> $$C_\text{srgb}=\begin{cases}
> 12.92C_\text{linear}, & C_\text{linear} \leq 0.0031308\\
> 1.055C_\text{linear}^{1/2.4}-0.055, & C_\text{linear} > 0.0031308
> \end{cases}$$

To utilize this, create a loop subprogram by adding a **Loop Input** node. Create this loop:

[image: sRGB encoding loop]

The numbers are truncated in the screenshot. Here they are, row by row:

```
0.003131
12.92
0.416667  1.055  0.055
```

Now, add 3 **Invoke Subprogram** nodes with **Separate** and **Combine Vector** nodes to encode the $R$, $G$, and $B$ channels.

[image: sRGB encoding]

Now, we need to get our vectors into a Vertex Color. [@Omar Ahmed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5794/omar-ahmad) has already made fabulous explanation of how to do this. You can find his answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/100463/26640). I will copy the relevant parts below, but I recommend reading his answer for a detailed (and illustrated!) explanation of how Vertex Colors work in Blender.

First, create this loop:

[image: Get face loops loop]

Then, create this script (make sure to name things properly):

[image: Set Vertex Col script]

Here is the script:

```
#Create a vertex color map named "Normals" if it is not already created.
if "Coords" in Object.data.vertex_colors:
    map = Object.data.vertex_colors["Coords"]
else:
    map = Object.data.vertex_colors.new("Coords")

#Loop over Colors and assign them to the vertex color map.
for i, color in enumerate(Colors):
    map.data[i].color = color
```

Finally, link up the last nodes (for an explanation of how they work, see the answer linked above). Here's the final tree:

[image: final nodetree]

#### Getting the coordinate system into Cycles

We will be using the **Point Density** node as I mentioned above. On the Cylinder object, create a new material. Add a **Point Density** node. Set it to *Object Vertices*, with the Coordinate Proxy as the object and the Color Source as Vertex Color. Choose the `Coords` Vertex Color. Next, disable visibility for the proxy object, and link the *Color* output of the **Point Density** node to an **Emission** node plugged into the **Volume** socket of the material output (in the picture I'm using the **Node Wrangler** add-on to get an **Emission** node):

[image: point density node]

Activate Rendered View in the viewport (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>). Position the 3D View so that you are looking at one of the "caps" of the cylinder. Adjust the *Radius* parameter of the **Point Density** node to be *just* big enough that there are no "gaps" ($0.1$ worked for me):

[image: wrong vs right radius]

Now we have our coordinates! Use the *Color* output just like you would normal texture coordinates, and volumetric texture-ize away!

[image: final render]

Just remember that anything you do to animate the cylinder also needs to be done to the proxy.

---

[image]
(Requires **[Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes)**)